# MySQL: fetch users groups and all it's members

Tags: mysql, performance, select

My table is of the following form which contains groups and it's members.

```
+---------+----+-------+
| group   | p  | state |
+---------+----+-------+
| group a | p1 |     3 |
| group a | p2 |     1 |
| group a | p3 |     0 |
| group a | p4 |     3 |
| group b | p1 |     1 |
| group b | p2 |  NULL |
| group b | p3 |     3 |
| group c | p2 |     1 |
| group c | p3 |  NULL |
| group c | p4 |     3 |
+---------+----+-------+
```

I want to fetch all the groups and it's members where `p1` is a part of.

I came up with this

```
select group, p from `groups` where group in (select DISTINCT group from `groups` where p = "p1")
```

The scale is of around 100,000 users per group and a user can be a part of any number of groups.
Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: If you value your sanity, do not use a reserved word as a table/column identifier.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, but the above table is a dummy table I created just for the sake of asking this question here. Didn't notice the insanity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try self join like this :

```
select t1.group,t1.p,t1.state
from groups as t1
inner join (
    select group
    from groups
    where p = 'p1'
) as t2 on t1.group = t2.group
```

Comment: How is it better than the query that I posted(which contains only a sub query) and also prevents an Inner Join? Is `Inner join` better than `in`?

Comment: INNER JOIN is generally a LOT better than using IN with a sub query. Problem comes when the INNER JOIN has multiple matches (as then you land up with 2 rows joining)

Comment: `( select group... )` --> `( select DISTINCT group ... )` to solve the "multiple matches".

Answer (score 0):

If 'p1' can only appear in each group once then you can do a simple JOIN:-

```
SELECT a.`group`, a.p
FROM `groups` a
INNER JOIN `groups` b
ON a.`group` = b.`group`
WHERE b.p = 'p1'
```